# How to automatically assign human readable labels to a topic?

Tags: r, lda, hierarchical-clustering, topic-modeling, topicmodels

[image]

Hi!

I ran a cluster analysis on my structural topic model and it resulted in 98 topics. How can I either a) manually assign topic names for each topic such that topic 98 could be called "teams" for example, or b) automatically assign topic names such that R determines a human readable name for topic 98?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, forgot R for a second, how would a human do it? How would you determine a "human readable" label? It's not very clear what you are after at all. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. If this isn't a specific programming question and you want general clustering advice, you should ask over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] instead.

Comment: I just looking to change the labels on this diagram so that instead of it saying the number 1 in this picture it would say "teams". Is their syntax for this relabeling?